# 2 Visual studios in 1?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have used IDEs like Netbeans and eclipse previously.

I downloaded "Visual studio express 2013 for windows desktop" in a friend's computer.
It was a single IDE and supported all.

I downloaded a "Visual studio express 2010" in my old computer. However I have two separate applications named "Visual C++ express", & "Visual C# express".

I would like to make a project using both C# and C++.
How can I use these two IDEs?
I want to be able to use a single IDE for my project like in VS2013.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use 2013? It's just as free.

Comment: You cannot run it unless you have win7 Sp1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to be able to use a single IDE for my C# and C++ projects like in VS2013.

You can't with VS 2010 - before VS 2012 each .NET language had its own Express version.

Starting with VS 2012 the [Express versions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express) were separated by *solution type* instead of by *language*.

> How can I use these two IDEs?

You'll have to build one project into a library and reference it in the other project.

Comment: Though I suppose you could just have them be separate solutions and just reference one compiled dll in the other IDE.

Comment: @Magus Sure, but you couldn't develop both C# and C++ projects in one IDE.

Answer (score 0):

From VS2012 Express versions includes C#, C++ and VB.NET tools in one application.
In VS 2010 create project in one IDE, build it and add to references to another project in another IDE.

Answer (score 0):

you can build a solution that has 2 different projects using different language types but you cannot mix langauge in the same project.

just get 2013 express, make your life simple and its better.